# Mysql matching weighted tags

Tags: mysql, sorting, matching

I have 3 tables:

- article (id, title, ...)
- article_tag (article_id, tag_id)
- tag (id, sort, ...)

I found a related article (to article with id 400 in example) by sorting on number of matching tags with:

```
SELECT at1.article_id, COUNT( at1.tag_id ) AS tag_count
FROM article_tag AS at1
INNER JOIN article_tag AS at2 ON at1.tag_id = at2.tag_id
WHERE at2.article_id = 400
GROUP BY at1.article_id
HAVING at1.article_id != 400
ORDER BY COUNT( at1.tag_id ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

This works fine. Now I wan't to add weight to the different kind of tags. In the table tag, there is a field named `sort`. This is an `int`, specifying the kind of tag. I wan't all the sorts to have different significance. I can put these multipliers in a different table or put them directly in the SQL-code (there is only 6 sorts). I would actually prefer the last method because then I can more easily tune the multipliers. How can I do this?

Comment: Let me get this straight... you're asking if you should store a value which could be changed as hardcoded well code... or as data in a table?  if the data can be changed. by whom, how frequently? and though what UI?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. My problem is how to write the new SQL, to make use of the multipliers. The multipliers can be either hardcoded or in a new table. But the problem is the new SQL...

Comment: Why not add a column to tag table called sort_weight or something... and then when you join to the tag table, it's accessible.  I'm assuming a tag.sort only has 1 possible weighting.  I guess I don't understand the requirement at this stage of weights and how it is used in relation to sort tags and the other data...  Sample data w/ expected results may clairify

Comment: The same values in sort_weight will then be stored on every single tag with that sort. Not very efficient. And the tag table is not joined at all right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression

```
SELECT at1.article_id,
       SUM(CASE at1.sort
            WHEN 1 THEN 5
            WHEN 2 THEN 3
            ...
            WHEN 6 THEN 15
           END) AS tag_weight
...
ORDER BY tag_weight DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Or you can join with a subquery that generates the associated weights.

```
SELECT at1.aticle_id, SUM(weights.weight) AS tag_weight
FROM article_tag AS at1
INNER JOIN article_tag AS at2 ON at1.tag_id = at2.tag_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS sort, 3 AS weight
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 3
    UNION
    ...
    SELECT 6, 15
) as weights ON at1.sort = weights.sort
WHERE at2.article_id = 400
GROUP BY at1.article_id
HAVING at1.article_id != 400
ORDER BY tag_weight DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Comment: Looks very clean. Are there any differences in performance with case and subquery?

Comment: I don't know offhand. Benchmark it and see. It probably depends on whether MySQL creates an index on the derived table.